# run time error 1004 application defined or object defined error - looping over same range in different worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

Could you please help me in solving the following issue:

```
Sub PBLSearch()

    Dim PBLRng As Range
    Dim PBL As Range
    Dim SearchRng As Range
    Dim SourceWsNr As Integer

    For SourceWsNr = 1 To 2
        Debug.Print Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets(SourceWsNr).Name
        Set PBLRng = Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets(SourceWsNr).Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
        For Each PBL In PBLRng.Cells
            Debug.Print PBL.Value
        Next PBL
    Next SourceWsNr

End Sub
```

The code works fine when the `SourceWsNr` equals 1, but as soon as this changes to 2, i get the error mentioned in the subject. 
Is it because i re-set the `PBLRng` variable? I couldn't find any solution to this problem...

Thank you very much in advance.

Best Regards,

S. Sz.

Comment: Where are you calling this macro? Behind a Sheet, ThisWorkbook, or module? My guess is you are calling from first sheet and so moving to next references unspecified ranges.

Comment: Do you get the error on the Debug.Print line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the line

```
Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets(SourceWsNr).Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown))
```

The `Range("A1")` and `Range("A1").End(xlDown)` are referencing the cells on the active worksheet which is why it fails on the second sheet (the arguments for the range method of a sheet have to be on the same sheet). You have to specify the sheet each time when calling `Range` This should do it:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SourceWsNr)
    Set PBLRng = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown))
End With
```

Edit: you might also consider using another way to find the last row, like `.Cells(.Rows.count,1).End(xlUp)`. It depends on your specific needs though.

Comment: I know i'm not supposed write only "thank you", but your answer was really helpful, so thank you very much !

Comment: @SándorSzilágyi glad I could help :)